# latest open SSL doesn't use tls?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I have error like this

```
$ curl https://packagist.jp/packages.json
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

At first I think this is because of obsolete SSL version.

However I updated openssl to latest one already.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
```

However even I use option for tls version but it shows the same error.

```
$ curl https://packagist.jp/packages.json --tlsv1.0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

$ curl https://packagist.jp/packages.json --tlsv1.1
curl: (35) Unsupported SSL protocol version

$ curl https://packagist.jp/packages.json --tlsv1.2
curl: (35) Unsupported SSL protocol version
```

Comment: Use `curl -V` to find out which version of OpenSSL your curl is actually using. Just because OpenSSL 1.0.2 is installed on your system it does not mean that older versions are not installed too (maybe only the library) and that curl uses these instead. *"However I updated openssl to latest one already."* - but you probably did not recompile curl to use this version.

Comment: Thank you very much!! my `curl -V` shows OpenSSL 0.9.8zd `curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd zlib/1.2.11 libidn/1.20 libssh2/1.4.3`.  I set the path for `/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.59.0/bin/curl` and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much!! my `curl -V` shows OpenSSL 0.9.8zd `curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd zlib/1.2.11 libidn/1.20 libssh2/1.4.3`  I make the path for `/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.59.0/bin/curl` and it works.